# I'm running Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04

I'm having issues with this Wi-Fi adapter usb drive worked before now doesn't run or show up on usb. I'm trying to connect wireless to my internet modem and doesn't give me any options. Only works if I plug in Ethernet cable.  Using netgear a6210 wifi adapter usb drive

Answer (score 1):

There are a some places you should try checking.
First I would try the *Additional Drivers* where you can enable third party closed software.

Another place would be to check with your USB model to see if the manufacturer has support for Ubuntu at all.

Also do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

I found this in git hub : https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210

follow the instillation in the bottom in git hub

it always helps to have everything up to date, or breaks, but hopefully helps.

Comment: I'm not a expert on linux Ubuntu. I have all the software installed for me and it was working next day my little brother was trying to play a game and did something and now it doesn't seem to show up read or recognize it.

Comment: Did you check the *Additional Drives* in the settings.

I found this in git hub : https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210

follow the instillation in the bottom in git hub